# Hooking get_pages()

Tags: hooks, pre-get-posts, pages

On a site this is a plugin that uses `get_pages()` to make a list of pages. The list is used to create a list of pages and create next page and previous page links. ( http://wordpress.org/plugins/next-page-not-next-post/ )

The structure of pages uses some empty pages just to make a hierarchy. Those pages are not in the navigation, which is controlled by `wp_nav_menu()`, but they are enlisted when the plugin calls `get_pages()`

So I want to remove those empty pages from the request made by the plugin.

My intent is to add a custom field to each unnecessary page, and to use this custom field to select and remove them.

I did a first attempt with `pre_get_posts` by:

1. use a function that collects an array of ID of pages with `get_pages()`
2. then use that array in conjunction with `post__not_in`and `pre_get_posts`

But it's a deadhead since the `get_pages()` launched by the plugin is not the main query.

So my question is : is there a hook to the `get_pages()` so I can filter its results and by so, affect the behaviour of the plugin ?

Comment: `get_posts` or `get_pages`? You mention both.

Comment: You mention hooks, but did you try using the arguments (especially `exclude`) that can be passed both to [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and [`get_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)? Does that parameter work? If not, why not? What happens?

Comment: @s_ha_dum : sorry, typo. I need to hook `get_pages()`.

@Chip_Bennett : I can't change the arguments without modifying the plugin, but i'd rather not to keep it updated regulary. That's why I would hook the function `get_pages()` : to change the result without changing the code of the plugin.

Comment: Below, in your own answer (which "doesn't work") you say "without using `get_pages()` so I am sorry but I don't really know what the question is or what needs to be solved. It is not clear.

Comment: Sorry. Don't know how to make it clear. The site uses a plugin. This plugin uses `get_pages()`. I want to change the behavior of this plugin without hacking its core. So I figured that I could change the `get_pages()` output, because it will change the output of the plugin. Doing so, I find how to filter `get_pages()`, and this is my solution below for documentation, but I also find out that the plugins uses two other functions that I cannot bypass or filter, so my attempt for this particular case is a dead-end.

Comment: @Simon  what you intend to do will lead to super super expensive queries, that will become extremely expensive as your site gets more traffic. NEVER tell a query what you DON'T want, always tell it want you DO want. Also don't use post meta to classify posts, that's what taxonomies are for. A custom taxonomy that has a term "this_is_necessary" will be thousands of times faster than a custom meta field that says "this_is_unnecessary", if not tens of thousands of times faster. I am not exagerating, and using a meta query this way will get more expensive as you add more posts in a serious way

Comment: As a sidenote, the plugin you're using is so small, why not just fork it? And if structure is what you're trying to provide, why do you need to use pages? Why not a hierarchical custom taxonomy applied to the pages post type?

Comment: @TomJNowell : you comment should be the answer : just don't do that.

Comment: @TomJNowell : too make a long story short : legacy code. I did it a very different way, but it was a long time, and I cannot rembember the specifics. Again, if you feel this thread is useless as a communautary content, we could delete it. Or just use your previous comment as a answer and I will validate it (the one saying just don't do that).

Answer (score 0):

I find the way, but it doesn"t work for my case because the plugin uses another function to link to parent pages, without using `get_pages()`so the result is so inconsistent. But the filter is working.

```
// Get all posts with the meta key 'not_in_menu'
function get_not_in_menu_posts() {

   $post_ids = wp_cache_get( 'wl_not_in_menu' );
   if ( false === $post_ids ) {

       $post_ids = array();
       $args=array(
           'post_type' => 'page',
           'meta_key' => 'not_in_menu',
                'meta_value' => '1'
       );

       $not_in_posts = get_posts( $args );
       if( $not_in_posts ) {
       $post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $not_in_posts, 'ID' );
   }

   wp_cache_set( 'wl_not_in_menu', $post_ids );
   }

   // return an array of IDs
   return $post_ids;
}

function exclude_pseudo_page( $posts ) {

   $excluded_posts = get_not_in_menu_posts();

   $shaved_posts = array();

   foreach ( $posts as $this_post ) {

       if ( ! in_array( $this_post->ID, $excluded_posts ) ) {
           $shaved_posts[] = $this_post;
       } 

   }

   return $shaved_posts;
}
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
   add_filter('get_pages', 'exclude_pseudo_page');
}
```

Feel free to comment.

Comment: "I find the way, but it doesn't work..." -- so is this or is this not a solution?

Comment: It's a solution to use a filter to exclude pages based on custom fields with `get_pages()`. But for my case, it does not bypass the plugin results for others reasons, so I can't use it. We could delete this thread if you think it's not worth it.